# When are peer-to-peer windows updates using the internet? Are they faster?

Tags: windows-10, internet, windows-update, peer-to-peer

I am curious about the practical effects of the Windows 10 setting for delivering windows updates using peer-to-peer downloading over the internet (as opposed to over just my local network).

That is, the setting `PCs on my local network, and PCs on the Internet` under `Choose how updates are deliviered`:

[image: Choose how updates are deliviered]

1. **When** is this peer-to-peer uploading to PCs on the internet in effect? Will my PC participate in uploading to the internet at all times when it is turned on? Or is it limited to the times when my PC is actually downloading updates?
2. Does enabling this option make the download significantly **faster** (compared to the option `PCs on my local network`)? That is, do I personally gain something from enabling this, or am I just being generous?

EDIT:

[This Microsoft FAQ](https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-10-windows-update-delivery-optimization) is the most authoritative source I have found. It states

> Delivery Optimization creates a local cache, and stores files that it has downloaded in that cache for a short period of time

It would be interesting to know what "a short period of time" is.

The FAQ doesn't say anything about any time limit on when the uploading can take place, so I'm inclined to assume that it is always on.

Comment: Enabling it might make a lot of sense if you have multiple computers on the same LAN. E,.g a small office with a dozen desktops. As soon one of them has downloaded the updates via the Internet access the other can get it at local LAN speed and they no longer need to use the often speed limited Internet connection. As to if it runs all the time: No idea.

Comment: @Hennes I absolutely have the first option to `On`, that is, I will at the very least enable `PCs on my local network`. My question is about what *additional* effects choosing the second radiobutton, `PCs on my local network, and PCs on the Internet` has.

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion when you enable peer to peer upload it will be working all the time when your Win 10 is running. Consequently your update-speed will be low because Microsoft will deliver its updates through your connection. Your bandwidth will be busy all the time with sending those updates. If you turn on PCs on local network only your local PC will get update from you PC only when users on you local pc click checking for update. Windows will find update inside LAN and will send it to your local PC only. So options with deliver update should speed ​​up updates on you local machines :)

Comment: Do you have any references to support your opinion?

Comment: For example this: http://tech.wp.pl/kat,1009779,title,Windows-10-podkrada-twoj-internet-Jak-to-wylaczyc,wid,17747648,wiadomosc.html?ticaid=117842

but it is in Polish language.

Comment: Microsoft provides little uses internet but... it can be different than true.
I'm IT System Administrator and I do not recommend turn this options

Comment: @Przemon even in Poland wp isn't reliable source of technical information. Please provide some better source

Comment: If I'm not mistaken and this peer to peer connection works anything like torrent I mean - goes beyond your LAN. Than yes it might greatly affect your internet connection.

Comment: Microsoft provide little use internet but, i to think its work like torrent. Microsoft said the peer to peer update witch are for example on your PC will start work when MS servers will be very busy...

Comment: [Here](http://lifehacker.com/windows-10-uses-your-bandwidth-to-distribute-updates-d-1721091469)'s a source, not sure how reliable it is though.

Comment: @RoughTomato LifeHacker is usually high quality. They claim it is faster. However, it doesn't sound like they made any actual measurements. Personally, I've always found Microsoft's download servers fast. Also, the article doesn't clarify when the peer-to-peer interaction is active.

Comment: @Klas Mellbourn peer-to-peer interaction is active when Microsoft servers are very busy and need help, i think. . .